# Alternative of odbc_result method for mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, odbc

A few days ago I have developed a PHP project with mssql server database. Right now I need to change the MSSQL database to MySQL database. Previously I have used the `odbc_result` method but I am converting the all methods of odbc to those of mysqli procedural. So I need a function that works like `odbc_result` for mysqli – which one is it? I am trying to use `mysqli_result` but it throws an error "Call to undefined function mysqli_result()".
Below I have menthid the function:

```
function checkCountry($con)
{
if ($con != '') {

    $cCodeList = array();
    $i = 0;

    $checkCountrySql = "SELECT country_code FROM country";
    $checkCountyResult = mysqli_query($con, $checkCountrySql);
    while (mysqli_fetch_row($checkCountyResult)) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= mysqli_num_fields($checkCountyResult); $j++) {
            $ar = mysqli_result($checkCountyResult, $j);
        }
        $cCodeList[$i] = $ar;
        $i++;
    }

    return $cCodeList;
    }
}
```

So what is the alternative of `odbc_result` for mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am trying to use `mysqli_result` but it was throwing an error *" Call to undefined function mysqli_result() "*.

Because there's no `mysqli_result()` function available in `MySQLi`.

Now look at the `for` loop, you're overwriting `$ar` in each iteration of the loop. In fact, you don't need this `for` loop at all, simply change your `while` loop in the following way,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($checkCountyResult)) {
    $cCodeList[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: after trying your solution I get duplicate value array

Comment: @AbaneelJahid Then use `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` query, `$checkCountrySql = "SELECT DISTINCT country_code FROM country";`. Plus, have you removed the following code block, `for( ... $i++;` ?

Comment: i have remove the for loop . there is no duplicate country_code under country table so i think no need to use DISTINCT keyword in sql

Comment: @AbaneelJahid Then `$cCodeList` should not contain any duplicate arrays. You must be appending something else in `$cCodeList` array, check this first.

Comment: I have given to your answer upvote. I didn't accept it as an answer because your answer working fine but it's not relevant to my question. I am searching the alternative of odbc_result

Comment: @AbaneelJahid In that case I would suggest you to write an answer and *accept* it to close the question, otherwise this question will be floating around SO as *open* question. Glad I could help. :-)